# Mod Rewrite - wrong links

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In .htaccess I have:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule documentation documentation.php?id=0
RewriteRule documentation/process documentation.php?id=1
```

when I open https://example.com/documentation/process correct website is called (documentation.php?id=1) but because I have links like "assets/css/xxx.css" instead "https://example.com/assets/css/xxx.css" my web site is not working correctly - basically it is pointing to wrong directories.
How can I fix that without changing all links to "https://example.com/assets/css/xxx.css"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it like this with anchors on both sides, using appropriate flags and `MultiViews` turned off:

```sh
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^documentation/?$ documentation.php?id=0 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^documentation/process/?$ documentation.php?id=1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Also you must add this just below `<head>` tag of your page's HTML:

```
<base href="/" />
```

so that every **relative URL** is resolved from that base URL and not from the current page's URL.